# Почему нам доступна возможность вызвать MemberwiseClone во время процесса клонирования?

Tags: c#, клонирование

Читая документацию по C# про метод `MemberwiseClone()` наткнулся на такой пример :

```
using System;

class MyBaseClass {
   public static string CompanyName = "My Company";
   public int age;
   public string name;
}

class MyDerivedClass: MyBaseClass {

   static void Main() {

   // Creates an instance of MyDerivedClass and assign values to its fields.
   MyDerivedClass m1 = new MyDerivedClass();
   m1.age = 42;
   m1.name = "Sam";

   // Performs a shallow copy of m1 and assign it to m2.
   MyDerivedClass m2 = (MyDerivedClass) m1.MemberwiseClone();
   }
}
```

У меня возник вопрос касательной вот этой строчки :

```
MyDerivedClass m2 = (MyDerivedClass) m1.MemberwiseClone();
```

Какое право мы имеем вызывать метод на объекте если в его сигнатуре прописан модификатор доступа `protected` ?

Comment: Ответ прост "внутри кода (метода) принадлежащему классу, мы имеем право обращатся (вызывать protected метод) к всем елементам protected которые принадлежат этому классу или к любому из списка наследуемых". MemberwiseClone находится в списке  наследуемых, а именно Object. Недаст сделать MemberwiseClone  - допустим строке String.

Answer (score 3):

Потому, что `MemberwiseClone` является методом класса `Objeсt` от которого наследуется `MyDerivedClass`, внутри которого и происходит вызов (`Main` тоже метод `MyDerivedClass`). Другими словами, внутри `MyDerivedClass` происходит вызов собственного protected-метода.

Если бы `MemberwiseClone` вызывался у стороннего класса не связанного отношением наследования с вызывающим, то была бы ошибка на этапе компиляции:

```
using System;

class Another {

}

class MyDerivedClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Another m1 = new Another();
        Another m2 = (Another) m1.MemberwiseClone(); // Error
    }
}
```